# How can I fully install a disc game before launching it

Tags: ps4

I have recently upgraded the hard drive on my PlayStation 4 and am currently in the process of restoring my current games to a playable state.

I have cycled through the game disks letting each one install (or at least allowing the progress bar under the game icon to complete) and downloading the relevant DLC and updates.

Unfortunately I am finding that some of them have not installed completely and only have enough data installed to launch the game (and presumably play the starting level or area) but not sufficient for me to load my progress without an inconvenient wait.

How can I force a disk game to perform a complete install? Or failing that identify when a game has only partially installed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to confirm a game is fully installed is to put the disc in and wait for it to install fully.  By which I mean, put the game disc in (but don't start it) and you'll hear the disc start to spin, if it's fully installed, after roughly three minutes you'll hear the disc stop spinning, if it doesn't stop, it's still installing and will stop the disc when it's finished.

Similarly when you first put the disc in it will keep installing from the disc and when it's done will stop the disc which is your cue to know it's done.

That's the only way I've ever been able to tell, the install progress bar is useless because that just tracks the install time of the data required to run the game, not the whole install.  The size on disc is equally unhelpful in this regard as each game will reserve space for its full install from the off, even if it's only currently installed a fraction of that.

All that said I've not noticed any particular issues with games only being partially installed and I can't see that extending beyond the first couple of sessions.